# Why in JavaScript can we omit params in first argument (callback) of reduce?

Tags: javascript, callback

We have this code:

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3]

const sumNumbers = (sum, num) => sum + num

// WORKS!
let a = nums.reduce(sumNumbers, 0)

// ERROR!
let b = nums.reduce(sumNumbers(sum, num), 0)
```

Why when I set `(sum, num)` in callback `sumNumbers` I got error:

> ReferenceError: sum is not defined

There is a name for this way of programming?

Comment: The first argument to `reduce()` is a callback function. So you pass a reference to the function, not a call of the function. The function will be called by `reduce()`, you don't want to call it immediately.

Comment: That's how callback functions work -- you pass the name of the function, you don't call the function yourself.

Comment: "*a name for this way of programming?*" - you've already mentioned it yourself: callbacks.

Comment: You get the error because there's no definition of `sum` or `num` on that line of code. You *could* call it like `let c = nums.reduce((sum, num) => sumNumbers(sum, num), 0);` if you wanted to be particularly verbose about it... There's no special name for this way of programming.